# Cleanup after deleteArchivedFiles.php?

Tags: mediawiki

Running `deleteArchivedFiles.php --delete` produces hundreds of these:

```
Searching for and deleting archived files...
Notice - file '2oh3r45yhkkolh6rkar4vva7d31e1at.zip' not found in group 'deleted'
Entry with ID 5 has empty key, skipping
Notice - file '6q5cx1ukqxcpa278khwpyiw8pel3pbe.zip' not found in group 'deleted'
Notice - file '5e11ue050bc9pt0zq16nlqhfsu3e25g.zip' not found in group 'deleted'
Notice - file '5e11ue050bc9pt0zq16nlqhfsu3e25g.zip' not found in group 'deleted'
Notice - file '5e11ue050bc9pt0zq16nlqhfsu3e25g.zip' not found in group 'deleted'
Notice - file '73zf180mu2iabieodv3s3vkmnadvvm5.png' not found in group 'deleted'
...
```

I suspect they are artifacts when a spammer got in. We got the spam accounts and spam messages cleaned up.

The Mediawiki manual page is at [deleteArchivedFiles.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteArchivedFiles.php), but it does not discuss cleaning further.

How do we fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not use MediaWiki so I cannot guide you further. Sorry. You are right about the documentation, it does not seem to be helpful on the topic. One page I found is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Combating_spam which focuses on prevention more than anything. That said, perhaps it is good jumping off point for you. You can also search for "clean up spam on Mediawiki" on Google. There may be something out there for you. Good luck. Cheers!!

Comment: Presumably you deleted the files manually so `deleteArchivedFiles.php` cannot find them?